# Plotting using scalar values. (vector/matrix/array input arguments are not accepted by code.)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-cvst

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to make a 2D plot of a function depending on only one variable. Cutting a long story short, the function can only accept scalar values; it will not accept vectors. Hence it is not possible to use, for example, `plot(vector, function(vector))`, for a range of independent values `vector`. I've tried to use loop also, but my knowledge is limited, and it hasn't worked in any case.

To summarise: I want to plot `function(x)` vs `x`, however `function` may only have a scalar input, so taking `x=-10:1:10` and then plotting it against `function` wouldn't work. 
Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi @Adriaan - Thank you for thr reply. I do understand that, but the fact that the function doesn't accept a vector means that it cannot be any other way. What I'm asking here is if there is another way to plot all of these scalar outputs which correspond to a range of input values? Is there a way to 'get around it'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
vector = -10:10 % set up your vector
output = zeros(size(vector); % initialise the output
for ii = 1:numel(vector)% loop over all elements of your vector
    output(ii) = function(vector(ii)); % feed the function a single element at a time
end

plot(vector,output) % Now you can plot the two vectors
```